# Combinatorics exercise

Tags: combinatorics

We have $2n$ ordered cells and $k \le n$ blocks. Each block occupies $2$ adjacent cells. How many ways can we place $k$ blocks into $2n$ cells? (blocks cannot intersect with each other).
A already know answer: $\frac{(2n-k)!}{(2n-2k)!}$, but a cant figure out how to achieve this result.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to say that you have $k$ blocks and $2n-2k$ unoccupied cells to arrange.

There are $\displaystyle {k + 2n-2k \choose k} =\frac{(2n-k)!}{k!\,(2n-2k)!}$ ways of arranging these.

But if the $k$ blocks are distinguishable then they can be among themselves ordered in $k!$ ways, so multiply together to give  $\displaystyle \frac{(2n-k)!}{\,(2n-2k)!}$ possibilities in total.

Comment: strictly speaking the first result is the answer to the question as asked ...